# netty HttpSnoopClientHandler.messageRecieved is not getting invoked

Tags: netty

I am getting started with netty. I was trying to play with the [HttpSnoop](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/snoop) example included in the source code. Although, I am able to get the HttpSnoopServer working i.e. I see responses in the browser window and I see the HttpSnoopServerHandler.messageReceived getting invoked, but I am unable to see the HttpSnoopClientHandler.messageReceived getting invoked at all. The HttpSnoopClient is not printing any of the server messages in stdout as expected. This is happening with the most current code as of this writing from the netty source. It is happening on windows and linux, any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: can you post some code which is causing the problem

Comment: I have not modified any of the code from the git repository. So I will just post the links: [client](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/snoop/HttpSnoopClient.java) , [clienthandler](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/snoop/HttpSnoopClientHandler.java) and [initializer](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/snoop/HttpSnoopClientInitializer.java)